# build a vector of char*

Tags: c++, string, pointers, char

I am trying to build a vector, and supposedly the each char* within the vector is different. Here is the code:

```
static char *StatsManager::_statsOption[4] = {"min", "max", "mean", "stddev"};

void BuildStatsNameList(long ChanIdx)
{   
    for (int m = 0; m < 4; m++)
    {
        std::string statsName(StatsManager::_statsOption[m]);

        for (int n = 0; n < 1; n++)
        {
            statsName += "_";
            statsName += std::to_string(ChanIdx);
            statsName += "_";
            statsName += std::to_string(n);
            //sprintf (statsName, "s%_%d_%d", StatsManager::_statsOption[m],ChanIdx, n);
            StatsManager::_statsNameList.push_back((char*)statsName.c_str());
        }
    }
}
```

However, I noticed the `char*` (`statsName` ) in the `statsName` will become the same eventually. 
For example after the loop, the `StatsManager::_statsNameList` becomes

```
stddev_1_0
stddev_1_0
stddev_1_0
stddev_1_0
```

......

instead, I want it as

```
min_1_0
max_1_0
mean_1_0
stddev_1_0
```

Anyone has any idea how to avoid the `statsName` getting overwritten again and again? Thanks.

Comment: Why `char*` instead of `std::string`?

Comment: You have undefined behaviour because you are storing pointers that get invalidated as soon as you leave the function. Why not store strings in the vector directly?

Comment: The interface from the other side is char*.

Comment: @Ono `The interface from the other side is char*`  You do know that std::string has a `c_str()` member function, right?  There is no reason whatsoever to write this code just because an entity somewhere else uses char*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want C-style strings that will persist, one option is to use [`strdup`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup).

```
   StatsManager::_statsNameList.push_back(strdup(statsName.c_str()));
```

Note, however, that you will need to `free` the memory yourself after you are done with those strings.

Answer (score 4):

Behavior of your program is undefined because you are accessing pointers to memory allocated in BuildStatsNameList function that has been deallocated as soon as BuildStatsNameList returns to the caller.

```
void BuildStatsNameList(long ChanIdx)
{   
    for (int m = 0; m < 4; m++)
    {
        std::string statsName( ...option[m]);  // local variable
        _statsNameList.push_back( (char*)statsName.c_str()); // no problem so far
        }
    }
}

// but here _statsNameList holds pointers to invalid memory
```

Consider usage of `std::vector< std::string>` instead or use `strdup` which will copy the c-string for you to new location ( if you absolutely have to stick to `char*`).

Comment: I am at your service sir

Comment: Sorry I took the other answer, but I tried your solution which works and upvoted it.